# TextView X + Y scroll on Android

Tags: android, webview, textview

I'm creating a text viewer app that has a `TextView`, I'm setting color on specific words using `SpannableString`. The text is long enough so it requires a Horizontal + Vertical `ScollView`.

But `HorizontalScrollView` inside `ScrollView` not giving me satisfactory results, so I'm thinking about using a `WebView`.

My question is, Should I use a `WebView` for this purpose? and if yes then does `WebView` has these abilities?

• Selectable Specific Words (by user)

• `SpannableString` support for color, text style (bold, italic)

• Custom font support (from .ttf)

UPDATE

I have implemented the `WebView` and those 3 abilities are working.

`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text,"text/html","utf-8",null);`

but I have a new issue, the text isn't scrolling horizontally anymore instead it's going on a new line. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [TwoWayNestedScrollView](https://github.com/ultimate-deej/TwoWayNestedScrollView).
I've never tried it but it seems to be well done and also it is quite recent.

Comment: Is it restricted to `ImageView` only? or every `View` will work as a child? (Especially `TextView`)

Comment: I think you can put any kind of View inside of it